# LDAP group membership authentication - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, openldap

I am new to LDAP and been playing around with this for a while now. I have a rails app where I need to authenticate a user if he is from a group. I tried few params but got nothing to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the devise_ldap settings and terminal output.

devise_ldap settings - ldap.yml

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: dc=skcript,dc=com
  required_groups:
    - ou=try1,dc=skcript,dc=com

    - ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]

  require_attribute:
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    authorizationRole: postsAdmin


development:
  host: localhost
  port: 389
  attribute: "uid"
  base: ou=try1,dc=skcript,dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=skcript,dc=com
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
  <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

[image: Terminal screen]

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: dc=skcript,dc=com    
  require_attribute:
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    authorizationRole: postsAdmin
    uniqueMember: ou=try1,dc=skcript,dc=com
```

required_groups checks your group dn against the uniqueMember attribute by default.

Check that the attribute storing group data in your LDAP server has the same name.

Don't forget to set this in your devise.rb :

```
config.ldap_check_attributes = true
```

For more information : https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/96